# insurance refund check made payable to me and my ex husband

Tags: united-states

we were to receive a $924. insurance refund due to overpayment on a house we sold. my ex husband had the check sent to his new address without telling me , signed his name and forged my name and cashed the check, when i found out about it and asked him  he admitted he forged the check and said there is nothing i can do about it. i called the insurance co they said its not up to them to police if its forged or not. do i call the police?  Should i call the bank that cashed the check? is small claims court really worth the trouble to get  half of $924?

Comment: Forgery is a crime, and he defrauded you out of $462.  There's only one thing for you to do: file a police report.  After that, law.SE will take over.  But you **can** with some work, get your money back and punish your ex-husband.

Comment: Only you can answer whether the effort to get the money back and to punish him is worth the effort.  But if you roll over, your ex thinks you're a chump and laughs about it.

Answer (score 4):

**You should call the police.**

If you talk to any bank they will say "well we had your signature on the cheque". They aren't in a position to perform criminal investigations.

You might first consider telling your husband that you are calling the police. After all, the downsides for him of having a criminal record, and whatever criminal punishment there is, will far outweigh $462.

However there is no guarantee that the police can prove anything. It may end up being your word against his. If you can do it legally you might try recording him admitting that he forged the cheque.

Comment: And if the police are unable to take action, a small claims case might at least recover the appropriate share of the funds.

Comment: My understanding of recording laws in the US is that only some states are '1 party consent states', meaning they allow only 1 person in the conversation to consent to recording the conversation. In some states, I believe that both people in a conversation must consent to being recorded. Without that determination from the OP, this advice runs the risk of advising an illegal act. [This is why the question is better suited to law.SE rather than money...]

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Did you read the part where I said "If you can do it legally"? That's what I meant.

Comment: Comparing known copies of her signature to the one on the check in question *should* do the trick.